# ReactiveMongo: How to deserialize a list into an Option

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Here below is a case class that represents an user, and its companion object provides a `BSONDocumentWriter` and `BSONDocumentReader` to serialize/deserialize to/from BSON:

```
case class User(
  id: Option[BSONObjectID],
  name: String,
  addresses: Option[List[BSONObjectID]]
)

object User {
  implicit object UserWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[User] {
    def write(user: User) = BSONDocument(
      "_id" -> user.id.getOrElse(BSONObjectID.generate),
      "name" -> user.name,
      "addresses" -> user.addresses
    ) 
  }

  implicit object UserReader extends BSONDocumentReader[User] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument) = User(
      doc.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id"),
      doc.getAs[String]("name").get,
      doc.getAs[List[BSONObjectID]]("addresses").toList.flatten,
    )
  }
}
```

The code above does not compile because `User.addresses` is an `Option` and I always get the following error:

```
/home/j3d/Projects/test/app/models/User.scala:82: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [B]List[B]
[error]  required: Option[List[reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID]]
[error]       doc.getAs[List[BSONObjectID]]("addresses").toList.flatten,
                                                                ^
```

If the input BSON contains `addresses`, how do I deserialize it into an `Option[List[BSONObjectID]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `toList` and then `flatten`?  If I'm reading the docs correctly for `BSONDocument`, the `getAs` method will return an `Option` for type `T` where in your case, you are specifying `T` as `List[BSONObjectID]`.  When you call `toList`, you are basically unpacking the `Option` to either an empty `List` (in the case of a `None`) or into the actual `List` in the case of a `Some`.  And then the `flatten` here doesn't seem to be doing anything relevant.  Can't you just do it as:

```
doc.getAs[List[BSONObjectID]]("addresses")
```